# Sitecore, JSS and GraphQL: licensing question

Tags: jss, licensing, graphql

The question is pretty simple: can I use the GraphQL from JSS package without JSS license?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a JSS license to use the `Sitecore.Services.GraphQL` package, which is essentially the "core" part of using GraphQL with Sitecore. So you are free to create your own schemas, extenders, etc... or use the built-in options.

There is a `Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.GraphQL` package as well. This package is primarily used to provide a custom JSS extender as well as a GQL rendering contents resolver for Layout Service. I don't believe the package *directly* requires a license, but it's not going to be of much use outside of a JSS context.

Comment: To expand on this, the GraphQL pieces ship as part of the JSS package, but the GraphQL API is entirely assemblies and configuration files - no items. It'd be a bit of effort to extract the right ones from the JSS package, but it will work.

Comment: Thank you, guys, for explanation! Very appreciate.